# Installed Package not found

Tags: python-3.x, package, installation-package

Can someone help explain how this is possible?   (https://github.com/TshepoMK/rootdescent)

[image]

I have uninstalled the package and re-installed, nothing happened. Installed on a different computer same thing, I have upgraded python to version 3.11, it requires 3.6.